# jQuery Change Value of Array Input With Skipped Indices

Tags: jquery, html

I have a function in Javascript that generates dynamic `<input>` elements when a button is clicked. The elements get structures as such:

```
<input name="array[0]" value="Value" />
<input name="array[1]" value="Value" />
```

What I need to do is via jQuery, replace the value of each of these elements. This would be pretty simple if the name was something like `name="array[]"`, as I could be able to call:

```
$("input[name='array[]']").each(function(e) {
  $(this).val("New Value");
})
```

To replace them all, but this functionality doesn't work with these `name="array[N]"` inputs. I wish I could use that first method, but I need the `[N]` indices for something later on the backend, and changing that would destroy almost all functionality.

Also, I've made a JSFiddle demonstrating this issue, feel free to debug with it.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/46o1npab/6/)

Comment: Like this -> http://jsfiddle.net/46o1npab/7/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [attribute starts with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/), [attribute ends with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/), or [attribute contains](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) selectors

```
$("input[name^='array[']") // starts with
$("input[name$=']'")       // ends with, probably not very useful here
$("input[name*='array']")  // contains
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks for that explanation! No one ever showed me those, would have been nice :P

Answer (score 2):

You could use the attribute starts with selector to match the inputs.

http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

```
$("input[name^='array']").each(function(e) {
  $(this).val("New Value");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

To directly answer your question, you can use the starts with (^) selector `"input[name^='second[']"`.  However I would recommend using a class and then using the apropriate selector

**DEMO :** http://jsfiddle.net/trex005/46o1npab/8/

Comment: Yeah, I suppose I could have used a class. This is my coworker's code and I'm not 100% sure where these inputs are coming from, which is why I opted to work with what I had. Thanks though!